# Translation for the old "ob"

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a word that's equivalent to the german ["ob"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ob_Praeposition)

> sie fielen ob ihrer sonderbaren Kleidung auf
> er war ganz gerührt ob solcher Zuneigung

Comment: Do you look for a "modern" German equivalent?

Comment: Putting in *English* or *German* after *looking for a* would make guessing unecessary, what you are after. The only indication is the *translation* tag currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An English equivalent that preserves both meaning and elevated language level would be 'for' with the meaning 'because of':

> "with fiery eyes sparkling for very wrath" (Shakespeare)

Answer (score 3):

In contemporary German one would use "wegen" or "aufgrund".

> sie fielen aufgrund ihrer sonderbaren Kleidung auf

> er war ganz gerührt wegen solcher Zuneigung